# Swapping nodes in a doubly linked list in C#

Tags: c#, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to sort a doubly linked list using bubble sort. I wrote the doubly linked list class myself. The nodes contain four values (firstName, lastName, Id and department).

The following are the methods I'm trying to use to sort the list (I'm using Windows forms and call the sortList method from the form).

K and I are Nodes of the doubleLinkedList class.

```
public DoubleLinkedList sortList(ref DoubleLinkedList toSort)
{
  for (toSort.K = toSort.First; toSort.K != endOfTheList(toSort.First); toSort.K = toSort.K.NextLink)
  {
    for(toSort.I = toSort.K.NextLink; toSort.I != endOfTheList(toSort.First); toSort.I = toSort.I.NextLink)
    {
      if (string.Compare(toSort.K.Department, toSort.I.Department) > 0)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(toSort.ToString());
        swap( toSort, toSort.K, toSort.I);
      }
    }
  }

  MessageBox.Show("List is sorted");
  MessageBox.Show(this.ToString());
  return toSort;
}

public void swap(DoubleLinkedList swapList, Node _k, Node _i)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Swapping " + swapList.K.ToString() + "for" + swapList.I.ToString());

    Node temp = _k;
    swapList.K = _i;
    swapList.I = temp;
    MessageBox.Show(swapList.K.ToString() + swapList.I.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(swapList.ToString());
}
```

The second last messagebox shows that the firstName, lastName, Id and department for the node K and node I have been swapped in the method, but they haven't actually swapped in the doublelinkedlist.

If anybody can give me advice on how I have to change these methods to actually swap the values in the list it would be much appreciated. I found examples online, but they were using the `LinkedList<>` class, and I'm really wanting to use my own class.

As an example: the Node K = Michelle Sellers, No12, Sales
                   Node I = Nick Hodges, No22, Accounts

After the swapping method, K = Nick Hodges, No22, Accounts and I = Michelle Sellers, No12, Sales, but in the actual list the nodes are not swapped.

Comment: What are `K` and `I`? Why do you write a sort algorithm for a specific type of node and not a more generic bubblesort with a comparator as parameter?

Comment: My guess is that your swap method isn't doing what you think it is.  As the above comment states, what are `K` and `I` ?

Comment: K and I are two nodes they are properties of my doublelinkedlist class. I was using them to loop through the list in the sort method to compare the nodes of the list with each other. I also forgot to mention that the list is supposed to be sorted by department in ascending order. So what i wanted to do was compare the department strings of two nodes and swap them if necessary.

Comment: @SelinaSchuh: But I don't understand why you store "loop counter" nodes in the linked list itself. Usually a datastructure should not take care of how an algorithm operates on it: it are the local variables of the algorithm that temporarely should store such loop counters.

Comment: You're right i did not do that in the beginning, in the beginning the method initialized a Node k and a Node i and i used them but i had the same problem so I thought maybe i need to store them in the list itself but that obviously did not solve the problem. I got the sort methods working with an array that stores integers but i can't seem to figure out how to do it with the linked list

Comment: Another thing, you each time call the `endofthelist` function?

Comment: yes i was wondering if i could use toSort.K != null instead...but priority at the moment is just to get it to work at all

Answer (score 0):

## Swapping nodes next to each other

Since you use BubbleSort, I'm going to **assume that the two nodes you want to swap are next to each other**. This is an assumption: if this does not hold; the problem is more complex.

Say you have a doubly linked list like the one below:

```
First                      Last
|                          |
v                          v
+---+ -> +---+ -> +---+ -> +---+
| 1 |    | 4 |    | 2 |    | 5 |
+---+ <- +---+ <- +---+ <- +---+
```

With `->` and `<-` the links to the `NextLink` and `PrevLink`. Now we want for instance to swap the nodes with `4` and `2`, then the list will be like:

```
First                      Last
|                          |
v                          v
+---+ -> +---+ -> +---+ -> +---+
| 1 |    | 2 |    | 4 |    | 5 |
+---+ <- +---+ <- +---+ <- +---+
```

So now we should ask ourselves: "What has changed": we see  a lot of changes:

- the `NextNode` of node 1 is now node 2;
- the `NextNode` of node 2 is now node 4;
- the `NextNode` of node 4 is now node 5;
- the `PrevNode` of node 5 is now node 4;
- the `PrevNode` of node 4 is now node 2; and
- the `PrevNode` of node 2 is now node 1.

Furthermore if one of the nodes to swap is the `first` node, or the `last` node, then we will have to update these pointers too. In that case there is usually no previous node for node 4 (in case node 4 was the `start` node), or no next node for node `2` (in case node 2 was the last node). So there are a lot of cases. This of course depends on whether the linked list has references to the `first` and/or `last` node.

So we can write an algorithm like:

```
public void swap(DoubleLinkedList swapList, Node i, Node j) {
    Node h = i.PrevNode;
    Node k = j.NextNode;
    if(swapList.First == i) {
        swapList.First = j;
    }
    if(h != null) {
        h.NextNode = j;
    }
    j.PrevNode = h;
    j.NextNode = i;
    i.PrevNode = j;
    i.NextNode = k;
    if(k != null) {
        k.PrevNode = i;
    }
    if(swapList.Last == j) {
        swapList.Last = i;
    }
}
```

## Swapping two random nodes

In case the nodes are random, the problem is more severe. Here we consider the scenario where we want to swap node `b` with node `f`:

```
     -> +---+ -> +---+ -> +---+ ->       -> +---+ -> +---+ -> +---+ ->
...     | a |    | b |    | c |     ...     | e |    | f |    | g |     ...
     <- +---+ <- +---+ <- +---+ <-       <- +---+ <- +---+ <- +---+ <-
```

In case we want to swap `b` with `f`, we will have to:

- let `a`'s `NextNode` be `f`;
- let `f`'s `NextNode` be `c`;
- let `e`'s `NextNode` be `b`;
- let `b`'s `NextNode` be `g`;
- let `c`'s `PrevNode` be `f`;
- let `f`'s `PrevNode` be `a`;
- let `g`'s `PrevNode` be `b`; and
- let `b`'s `PrevNode` be `e`.

So we can implement this like:

```
public void swap(DoubleLinkedList swapList, Node b, Node f) {
    Node a = b.PrevNode;
    Node c = b.NextNode;
    Node e = f.PrevNode;
    Node g = f.NextNode;


    if(swapList.First == b) {
        swapList.First = f;
    } else if(swapList.First == f) {
        swapList.First = b;
    }

    if(a != null) {
        a.NextNode = f;
    }
    f.PrevNode = a;
    f.NextNode = c;
    if(c != null) {
        c.PrevNode = f;
    }

    if(e != null) {
        e.NextNode = b;
    }
    b.PrevNode = e;
    b.NextNode = g;
    if(g != null) {
        g.PrevNode = b;
    }

    if(swapList.Last == b) {
        swapList.Last = f;
    } else if(swapList.Last == f) {
        swapList.Last = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the nodes are not necessarily next to each other. i know bubblesort is not an efficient way of sorting the list but i need to use it..

Comment: @SelinaSchuh: I have the idea you did not implement bubblesort, since in bubblesort, all swaps are always next to each other https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: it doesn't say the nodes have to be next to each other?

Comment: @SelinaSchuh: "*Starting from the beginning of the list, compare every **adjacent** pair, swap their position if they are not in the right order*".

Comment: alright then do have any suggestions on how i can sort the list or not?

Comment: @SelinaSchuh: well this question is about swapping. But the Wikipedia page mentions how to build a bubble-sort algorithm on top of that.

Comment: like i said before i got it working with an array...and the integers that are swapped are not always next to each other. oh and sorry i'll correct myself do you have any suggestions on how i can _**swap the nodes**_ ?

Comment: Did you test that ? Because I tried that as well Thi king it definitely should work but then all other nodes in the list are gone

Comment: @SelinaSchuh: yes I tested this.